# Memory consumed by EHCache same as HashMap

Tags: java, ehcache, heap-memory

We are evaluating the use of EHCache in our project. We tested by using a simple hashMap and since the size could overshoot the heap size we wanted to ensure that we could control that.. hence EHCache. But I am not able to understand this..

If I put a 500,000 entries into a HashMap, the memory consumed is about 114MB. If I use EHCache and limit the number of entries in the heap to 10 and local disk to 500000 it consumes 98MB. I dont see a great difference. I was thinking that I should be able to see only a small amount of heap used since only 10 entries are in the heap. Here are the programs I running..

HashMap Program..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1024/1024);

        NastIDAccountID accountIDNastID=new NastIDAccountID();
        for(int i=0;i<500000;i++){
            System.out.println(accountIDNastID.getFromCache(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024);
    }

    public static class NastIDAccountID{
        private final Map<String,String> cache;

        public NastIDAccountID() {
            this.cache = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        public String getFromCache(String key){
            if(cache.containsKey(key)){
                return cache.get(key);
            }else{
                final String value = key + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                cache.put(key, value);
                return value;
            }

        }
```

EHCache Program:

Cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="false">

    <diskStore path="/Users/temp/ehcachepersist"/>

    <cache name="nastIDMossoIDMappingCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="500000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           maxElementsOnDisk="1000000"
      />
</ehcache>
```

Program:

```
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.constructs.blocking.CacheEntryFactory;
import net.sf.ehcache.constructs.blocking.SelfPopulatingCache;


public class EHCacheTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1024/1024);

        final CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create(EHCacheTester.class.getResource("ehcache.xml"));
        final Cache nastIDMossoIDMappingCache = cacheManager.getCache("nastIDMossoIDMappingCache");

        NastIDAccountID accountIDNastID=new NastIDAccountID(nastIDMossoIDMappingCache);
        for(int i=0;i<500000;i++){
            System.out.println(accountIDNastID.getFromCache(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println("nastIDMossoIDMappingCache.calculateInMemorySize() = " + nastIDMossoIDMappingCache.calculateInMemorySize());
        System.out.println("nastIDMossoIDMappingCache.calculateOnDiskSize() = " + nastIDMossoIDMappingCache.calculateOnDiskSize());
        System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024);
        cacheManager.shutdown();
    }

    public static class NastIDAccountID{
        private final Ehcache cache;

        public NastIDAccountID(Ehcache cache) {
            this.cache = new SelfPopulatingCache(cache, new OurCacheEntryFactory());
        }

        public String getFromCache(String key){
            return (String)cache.get(key).getValue();
        }
    }

    public static class OurCacheEntryFactory implements CacheEntryFactory{
        private int counter;
        @Override
        public Object createEntry(Object o) throws Exception {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
            return o.toString()+ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        }
    }
}
```

I have printed the cache size. The cache in memory size is only 2960 bytes. But the heap size as reported by Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() is telling me something different.

The bottom line is EhCahe is using the same amount of memory as a HashMap!

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache won't reduce the amount of garbage produced, in fact because it is doing much more work, it could produce much, much more (esp. if you use Java Serialization) What it does for you is reduce the amount retained, something you can only see after Full GC (e.g. `System.gc()`)